# postgresql :: retrieve row matching exact condition or number of rows matching part of condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, lazy-evaluation

I have table "permission" like

```
| user_id | object_id | readable | writable |
```

I need to find out if the given **object_id** can be accesible by current **user_id** with following rules:

- if there is no records for **object_id** at all, then return true
- if there is a record for **object_id** but for different **user_id**, while there is no record for given **user_id**, then return false
- if there is record for given **user_id** and **object_id**, then check agains provided readable and writable conditions

I'm not sure if it's possible to build SQL query, which wouldn't involve nested queries, for now I came out with

```
select (
    select count(*) 
    from permission 
    where 
        object_id = 123456
    ) == 0 OR (
        select readable=true, writable=false 
        from permission 
        where user_id=1 and object_id=123456
    )
```

Is there a more elegant solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT count(*) as total_count, --count of permission records for object
       bool_or(user_id = 1 AND readable) as user_readable, -- user has read permission, null if no permission record
       bool_or(user_id = 1 AND writable) as user_writable, -- user has write permission, null if no permission record
FROM permission
WHERE object_id = 123456
```

Then build your logic cases from this query like:

```
SELECT total_count = 0 OR user_readable as readable,
       total_count = 0 OR user_writable as writable
FROM (first select here)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
select 
  case 
    when (not exists (select object_id from permissions where object_id=123456)) then true
    when (not exists (select * from permissions where object_id=123456 and id=1)) then false
    else <check your conditions here> 
  end;
```

It is slightly less efficient that araqnid's query, but could be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
select true as readable, true as writable
where not exists (select 1 permission where object_id = 123456)
union all
select readable, writable
from permission
where user_id = 1 and object_id = 123456
```

Note you have disjoint possibilities:

- No permissions exist for the object
- Permissions exist for the object

  - Permission exists for the user
  - No permission exists for the user

That is, if no permissions exist then return true. Otherwise return the permission for the user. If there are permissions that exist but not for this user, return nothing (and you could make the query explicitly return "false, false" in this case, but why waste effort?)

Also, this assumes that `(object_id, user_id)` is a unique key for the `permission` table.

Comment: @jdevelop try it with your dataset and tell us!